# Reutilizar una funcion JS

Tags: javascript

Hola con la siguiente linea de código, como hago para modificarlo e imprimir la cantidad de cada tipo de fruta utilizando la misma función?

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango","Orange", "Orange", 
"Apple", "Mango"];

var cant = fruits.filter(function(value) {
    return value == "Orange";
})

console.log(cant.length);
```

Comment: ¿Que intentaste? Porque preguntar solo por preguntar, no es la idea de SO, debes haber intentado algo y mostrar que problema te esta generando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes crear una funcion que acepte un Array y un elemento x a buscar, y devuelva la cantidad de elementos x encontrados iguales

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango","Orange", "Orange", 
"Apple", "Mango"];

function myFunction(myArr, xelement ) {
    return (myArr.filter(x => x == xelement )).length;
}


console.log(myFunction(fruits,"Orange"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay otras formas de contar la cantidad de veces que un elemento se repite dentro de un array, pero usando tu código puedes hacer lo siguiente iterando cada elemento y verificando si es que ya se ha filtrado el array por ese elemento.

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Orange", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"
];

var counted = [];

fruits.forEach(function(element) {
  if (!counted.includes(element)) {
    var cant = fruits.filter(function(value) {
      return value == element;
    }).length;
    counted.push(element);
    console.log(element + " = " + cant);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Algo simple podría ser usando encapsulando tu filter

```js
const frutas = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango","Orange"];

const contarFrutas = (valor, listaDeFrutas) => (
  listaDeFrutas.filter(fruta => fruta === valor).length
); 

console.log(
 contarFrutas('Banana', frutas)
);

console.log(
 contarFrutas('Orange', frutas)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango","Orange"].reduce(function (array, index) {

  array[index] ? array[index]++ : array[index] = 1
  return array;
}, {});

console.log(a)
```